# Endpoint adds _header property to JSON response object

Tags: javascript, json, get

I'm testing pulling data from a remote endpoint service (npoint.io). When I get the response object back, it adds the "_headers" property to my JSON.

I suppose I can delete the property when I stringify the JSON. But asking because perhaps I'm missing an optional parameter in my `http.get()` that I should be using to remove this.

First, here is the response from the server:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Simple Test",
        "required": [],
        "properties": {}
    },
    "data": {},
    "_headers": {
        "cache-control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
}
```

I'm expecting:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Simple Test",
        "required": [],
        "properties": {}
    },
    "data": {}
}
```

Comment: Can't you just ignore the extra property?

Comment: I can. I'm just wondering if there's something I'm missing in the http.get() optional params that would prevent it from being included in my JSON.

Comment: Are you sure `http.get()` is doing this? If you call the endpoint with `curl` or `wget` does it have this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't studied the API documentation of **npoint.io**, maybe there is a query parameter you could add to get rid of it?

I think they are only trying to be 'friendly' by repeating the headers they are setting for the response in JSON. Although a bit unnecessary because you can read the response header directly in JS if you want to...

I would just ignore it and delete that property, it isn't that much of an extra overhead counted in bytes :)